# Hide li tag if the URL is empty

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the following to show a users facebook and twitter links.

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li style="padding-right:20px;">
    <a href="https://{{channel.facebook_page}}" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="{{channel.channel_name}} On FaceBook"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" style='color:#ee6f00'></i></a>
  </li>
   <li>
   <a href="https://{{channel.twitter_page}}" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="{{channel.channel_name}} On Twitter"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" style='color:#ee6f00'></i></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Sometimes my site users don't have facebook or twitter accounts. So is there a way of hiding the `li` if the `href` value after the `https://` is empty. In other words if my `{{channel.facebook_page}}` is blank hide `th li`.

Comment: What framework is the {{...}}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what framework you are using for templating I will take a stab at it and guess Angular based on your tags in your profile.

You can use Angular's with [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) to show the element if it evaluates to be truthy

```
<li 
  ng-if="channel.facebook_page"
  style="padding-right:20px;">
    <a href="https://{{channel.facebook_page}}" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="{{channel.channel_name}} On FaceBook"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" style='color:#ee6f00'></i></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Yes im using angular and your answer worked a treat thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

A script would be one obvious solution, though there is one more.

Use the CSS attribute selector `[attribute='value']`, and do something like this.

```
a[href='https://'] {
  display: none;
}
```

---

And for the *padding* set on the `li`, use a `margin` on the anchor `a` instead, and you can solve this with CSS alone, and get the same visual result as hiding the `li`.

Comment: should be `li` though

Comment: Thanks bro, but as another guy spotted I was using angular and gave me a good solution but thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You could do the `a[href='https://']` selector that @LGSon used in his CSS, but use it in your javascript, then get the parentElement and set it to `display: none`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[href="https://"]').forEach(function(el) {
    el.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li style="padding-right:20px;">
    <a href="https://" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="{{channel.channel_name}} On FaceBook"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" style='color:#ee6f00'></i> Facebook</a>
  </li>
   <li>
   <a href="https://twitter.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="{{channel.channel_name}} On Twitter"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" style='color:#ee6f00'></i> Twitter</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

@LGSon is on the right track, but his answer only hides the hyperlink, not the `li` parent of it.

This would do the trick:

```js
// Get all the hyperlinks that don't have anything after "https://" into an array and loop the array
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href='https://']")).forEach(function(link){
  link.parentElement.classList.add("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; } /* Add this class to any element that should be hidden */
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li><a href="https://something">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**NOTES:**

- `.forEach()` is not universally supported on node lists in all
  current browsers, so converting the node list returned by
  `.querySelectorAll()` is required to ensure cross-browser support.
- It is generally better to work with CSS classes, rather than
  adding/removing inline styles. This promotes more reusability and
  less code redundancy. Use the **[`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** property for easy access.